# How to escape the dollar sign in pre-build step

Tags: visual-studio-2013

'm fighting against Visual Studio to properly escape the dollar sign ($) in a pre-build step. The goal is to provide a variable name as a litteral. VS should not try to process the variable name.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819(v=vs.120).aspx) states that %xx (where xx is the hexadecimal value of the character) should be used.

I've tried the following :

```
%24(var.Data.WebHost.ProjectDir)
```

But the result is

```
4(var.Data.WebHost.ProjectDir)
```

Instead of

```
$(var.Data.WebHost.ProjectDir)
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

UPDATE 1 : the correct syntax is to put the $ sign between double quotes.

```
"$"(var.Data.WebHost.ProjectDir)
```

is the answer.

Comment: The problem is that you got exactly what you asked for, MSBuild indeed did not process the variable name. So %24(yadayada) got copied into the prebuild event. Which is executed by the command processor, Cmd.exe. Which treats %2 specially, it substitutes it with the 2nd command argument. Nothing. You *do* want MSBuild to expand that variable.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative using the approach in the documentation would be to do:

```
%2524(var.Data.WebHost.ProjectDir)
```

`%25` does the `%`, while the remaining `24` will be appended, forming `%24`, thus translating into `$(Whatever)` in the output code.

The `"$"` approach didn't work for me as I was writing an osx-compatible post build event (for mono 5), so I needed something like this:

```
if [ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]; then (...)
```

And the output, `""$"(uname)"` didn't work for me.

I hope this late answer is helpful to anybody in the future (as there does not seem, down to this point, to have much about this issue on google).