# Escaping a dollar sign in Postbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, post-build

I'm trying to execute a command in Postbuild which uses a dollar sign. I've tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200556/how-to-escape-the-dollar-sign-in-pre-build-step) but none work.

```
echo "$(runtime.testbin)"
```

Trying to do this throws an exception when I try to build, I tried escaping with:

```
echo "%24(runtime.testbin)"
```

But this prints:

`1>  "4(runtime.testbin)"`

I've also tried:

`echo "%2524(runtime.testbin)"`

which prints:

`1>  "524(runtime.testbin)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to encode the dollar sign and the following parenthesis (not necessarily the closing parenthesis but I personally think it looks ugly encoding just one of them):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>echo "%24%28hello%29"</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. After saving the .csproj with encoding, it works like a charm!

Comment: Tbh i had to call MSBuild's internal `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IntrinsicFunctions.Encode()` method to find out how to properly encode this..

Answer (score 0):

Does your command has to be something like: `$(runtime.testbin)`?

In msbuild, the format `$(xxx)` would be recognized as value of [Msbuild Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#define-and-reference-properties-in-a-project-file).

Maybe you can try:

`echo $ (runtime.testbin)`=>$ (runtime.testbin)

`echo "$ (runtime.testbin)"`=>"$ (runtime.testbin)"

`echo $ runtime.testbin`=>$ runtime.testbin

`echo $:(runtime.testbin)`=>$:(runtime.testbin)

**Update:**
Martin's answer works like a charm! Actually simple encoding the file can make the `echo "%24(runtime.testbin)"` work.